# How to split string surrounded by separators

Tags: python, list, split

How can I indicate that everything between { and } is a list of its own and everything inside of quotes but between a comma is a row in the list?

I'm using python 3 and pulling data from a website with 'request'. The website URL feeds me data in a format where it's separated by being enclosed in various characters.

```
URL = 'https://url.tld/thing?stuff&more_stuff'
request = requests.get(URL, auth=(USER,PASS))
request = request.content.decode('utf-8')
print(request)
print(type(request))
```

Result:

```
[{"domain":"aaa.local","os":"2","hostname":"srv1.nyc","location":"Townsville, New York"},{"domain":"bbb.local","os":"3","hostname":"srv2.lax","location":"Compton, California"}]
<class 'str'>
```

which can be thought of like this:

```
[{+-----------+----+----------+----------------------+
  | domain    | OS | hostname | location             |
  +-----------+----+----------+----------------------+
  | aaa.local | 2  | srv1.nyc | Townsville, New York |
  +-----------+----+----------+----------------------+},
 {+-----------+----+----------+----------------------+
  | domain    | OS | hostname | location             |
  +-----------+----+----------+----------------------+
  | bbb.local | 3  | srv2.lax | Compton, Californa   |
  +-----------+----+----------+----------------------+}]
```

If I define it as a list without a separator, it comically puts every single character as an element inside of 1 list. If I define it as a list and the split is },{ then it all just one list.

ideally it would look like this if i manually typed it in a python list:

```
[['domain:aaa.local','os:2','location:Townsville, New York'],['domain:bbb.local','os:3','location:Compton, California']]
```

With '},{' as the split, i get something close.

```
['[{"domain":aaa.local","os":"2","location":"townsville, new york"','"domain":bbb.local","os":"3","location":"compton, california"}]']
```

Comment: A simple split won't help you with this type of problem, but you could write a regex that deals with the curly braces. However, why are you trying to turn something that is more like a dictionary (a Python data type) into a list to begin with? Look into `json.loads` for what you probably need.

Comment: What is the actual output/final result which you want here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `request()` is giving you back a list of two dicts in string form. So, you can just `eval()` it to make it into an actual list of two dicts. So,

```
my_list = eval(str(request))
```

`type(my_list)` --> list

Actually, what's in between the { and } is not a list but rather a dict...

Comment: interesting. dictionaries aren't a thing I knew existed. I suppose I should just quit trying to teach myself and seek formal education. maybe then I could ask a question without getting neg votes but then again, if I knew what I were doing, i wouldn't be asking here ¯\_(ツ)_/¯